# How can I append to an existing csv dictionary or add line with python csv?

Tags: python, csv, praw

I'm using PRAW to get information to write general information to a csv. When I run the code to append the data it doesn't append existing information, just adds a new line for the same submission even though it should be checking for repeating id's.

```
with open('dummycsv.csv', 'r+', newline= '') as f:
    fieldnames = ['ID', 'Subreddit', 'Karma']
    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
    thewriter.writeheader()
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:          #opens flie for later reading
        iden = row['ID']
        sub = row['Subreddit']          #assigns names for the columns for comparisons
        score = row['Karma']
        for submission in reddit.subreddit('all').hot(limit=5):         #begin going through reddit via PRAW
            if iden == submission.id:       #if id is already in file, updates the score of the post
                thewriter.write("{},{},{}".format(iden, sub, submission.score))

            else:       #if a new post, writes a complete row
                thewriter.writerow({'ID' : submission.id, 'Subreddit': submission.subreddit, 'Karma':submission.score})
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify contents that was already written to a file?

Comment: Yes, modify one of the fields if the id exists already, otherwise add a new line

Comment: I don't think modification is possible with `DictReader`. I think it just always appends to the file. You could look into keeping all the data in a list first, modify the values in the list and then use the `writerows` method at the end to write all of the data at once to the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that you could do this.

Though none of them allow you to read the data in and write to that data at the same time (and is generally frowned upon).

One method is to use the built-in CSV library to read in all of your data from your csv. Do your data manipulation and then write that data back to a csv.

```
with open('dummycsv.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    rows = [row for row in spamreader]
# use the rows data as you wish (rows[0] are the headers of the file)
# continue with praw operations checking that the id is not in the id column
# assumng that the id column is the first column because of your fieldnames array
id_dict = {v[0]: c for c,v in enumerate(rows[1:])} # for quick look up of the id

# PRAW analysis
for submission in reddit.subreddit('all').hot(limit=5): # go through reddit via PRAW
    row_value = id_get.get(submission.id)
    if row_value:       #if id is already in file, updates the score of the post
        rows[row_value + 1] = [submission.id, sub, submission.score]
    else:       #if a new post, writes a complete row
        rows.append([submission.id, sub, submission.score])

# write back to same file 
with open('dummycsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['ID', 'Subreddit', 'Karma']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for i in rows[1:]:
        writer.writerow({'ID': rows[0], 'Subreddit': rows[1], 'Karma': rows[2]})
```

Another method that you could use is to use the Pandas package to read and write to the csv in probably fewer lines than what I wrote, but I am not proficient with that package to give good advice in using it yet.